# Find SUM of columns with condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Roll no. |Sub1|sub2|
1.        |20. |50. |
2.        |80. |90. |
```

The sample data is given about now I need to find out the roll number where the sum of subject Sub1 and Sub2 is more than 100

I try this but no luck

```
Select (sub1+sub2) as total
from table 
where total > 100
```

Comment: You can't use the column alias in the WHERE clause, because the WHERE clause is evaluated _before_ the SELECT clause.

Comment: I'd simply repeat the `sub1 + sub2` in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the calculation in the where condition as well, because the where condition is processed before the select-statement.

```
Select (sub1+sub2) as total
from table 
where (sub1+sub2) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use alias but outside of query by using CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE tblName (roll_number INT, sub1 INT, sub2 INT);

INSERT INTO tblName (roll_number, sub1, sub2) VALUES (1 ,50, 20);
INSERT INTO tblName (roll_number, sub1, sub2) VALUES (2, 110, 20);
INSERT INTO tblName (roll_number, sub1, sub2) VALUES (3, 120, 20);
INSERT INTO tblName (roll_number, sub1, sub2) VALUES (4, 30, 20);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT roll_number AS RollNumber, (sub1 + sub2) AS Total
    FROM tblName
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE Total > 100
```

Returns:

| RollNumber | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 130 |
| 3 | 140 |

Tested on MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score -1):

your can try this simple query

```
 WITH 
CTE1 AS (SELECT SUM(`sub1`+`sub2`) AS subject_total,id as roll_num FROM `tbl` group by id ) 
SELECT * FROM CTE1 
WHERE subject_total > 100;
```

Demo [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f12c5f905f9bd2e2aeb0a0fb0a416b3c)

Comment: The requirement is: "I need to find out the roll number where the sum of subject Sub1 and Sub2 is more than 100". Does your query return roll numbers?

Comment: just to add in roll number column in CTE1 query likeWITH
    CTE AS(
    SELECT
        SUM(`sub1` + `sub2`) AS subject_total,
        id AS rollnumber
    FROM
        `tbl`
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    subject_total > 10;

Comment: This query does not even run. Try it.

Comment: it working in 10.4.22-MariaDB. please share you error or Image exactly

Comment: Can you share a working link of a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4?

Comment: `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` this is the error you will get if you have sql_mode=only_full_group_by and don't use group by. Check this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59409070f82564891882e71a4406e63b) for better explanation.

Comment: ok i forgot the group by id try below query     WITH 
CTE1 AS (SELECT SUM(`sub1`+`sub2`) AS subject_total,id as roll_num FROM `tbl` group by id ) 
SELECT * FROM CTE1 
WHERE subject_total > 100;

Comment: check demo link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f12c5f905f9bd2e2aeb0a0fb0a416b3c

Comment: What is id? There is no id in the table.

Comment: "id" it's a Roll no.in your query